# nvm is not recognised command

Tags: angular, npm, nvm

I have installed nvm for windows along with two versions of nodes following this link.

https://medium.com/appseed-io/how-to-run-multiple-versions-of-node-js-with-nvm-for-windows-ffbe5c7a2b47

The node versions installed are 8.12.0 and 7.3.0. I was able to run the nvm use command at the global level . Suddenly after a restart of my machine , I am not able to run it globally from my command prompt. I get errors nvm is not recognised command however I can see the nvm path set in the environmental variables.

Not sure what the problem is ?

Comment: what is the output of `whoami` and `whereis nvm`?

Comment: have you added the nodejs directory to your PATH environment variable?

Comment: Yes. Its there. Restarting the computer worked

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you get an issue like this in windows, try running

```
refreshenv
```

This updates the environment variables in your command window (or Powershell) without having to restart the computer.